# Bitmap.LockBits giving wrong values?

Tags: c#, windows, gdi

I have an issue while changing some code from Bitmap.GetPixel to using a direct pixel buffer returned by LockBits. It seems that the returned data by LockBits does give me different Color values compared to GetPixel.

That is unfortunate since this change does produce different colors which would break automated unit tests. I have a png file of 29*30 pixel which I do load a Format32bppArgb into a bitmap. Can this really be that the data returend by LockBits and GetPixel are different. How can I get around this?

Here is some code to repro it with a loaded bitmap

```
public unsafe static Bitmap Convert(Bitmap originalBitmap)
{
    Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(originalBitmap);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, converted.Width, converted.Height);
    var locked = converted.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, originalBitmap.PixelFormat);
    byte* pData = (byte*)locked.Scan0;

    // bytes per pixel
    var bpp = ((int)converted.PixelFormat >> 11) & 31;

    byte* r;
    byte* g;
    byte* b;
    byte* a;

    for (int y = 0; y < locked.Height; y++)
    {
        var row = pData + (y * locked.Stride);

        for (int x = 0; x < locked.Width; x++)
        {
            a = row + x * bpp + 3;
            r = row + x * bpp + 2;
            g = row + x * bpp + 1;
            b = row + x * bpp + 0;
            var col = Color.FromArgb(*a, *r, *g, *b);
            var origCol = originalBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
            if (origCol != col)
            {
                Debug.Print("Orig: {0} Pixel {1}", origCol, col);
            }

        }
    }
    converted.UnlockBits(locked);

    return converted;
}

Orig: Color [A=128, R=128, G=128, B=255] Pixel Color [A=128, R=127, G=127, B=255]
Orig: Color [A=0, R=128, G=128, B=255]   Pixel Color [A=0, R=0, G=0, B=0]

Orig: Color [A=45, R=128, G=128, B=255]  Pixel Color [A=45, R=130, G=130, B=254]
                                                       ok     -2      -2     +1
```

Most of the time but there seems to be some rounding and conversion to be going on. Can I force LockBits to return data as it would be returned by GetPixel?

Comment: Can't PNGs contain colour profiles/gamma settings/whatever? Perhaps `GetPixel` retrieves the  colour of the pixel with respect to the colour profile. Obviously the raw ARGB values can't store the colour profile, so you see different results.

Comment: Your bpp variable is an attempt at dealing with the pixel format.  But can't actually work unless it is a 32bpp image.  At least ask for the pixel format you need in the LockBits() call.  PArgb will be a problem.  It would work by also using LockBits() on the original image.  But then there's not really any point to the code anymore.

Comment: I did find some 24/32bpp images in my test data. Yes I do reject everything else. The bpp variable extraction code does in fact not work at all since it does report the wrong number of bytes back. Now I have a switch case with the supported formats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, PNGs can contain colour profiles and gamma correction information and whatever else which can affect the final colour of pixels vs. their raw representation.

Even if we disregard specific knowledge about PNGs, in general `GetPixel` can return different values than is expected.

`Bitmap.GetPixel` is implemented thus:

```
public Color GetPixel(int x, int y)
{

    int color = 0;

    if (x < 0 || x >= Width)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("x", SR.GetString(SR.ValidRangeX));
    }

    if (y < 0 || y >= Height)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("y", SR.GetString(SR.ValidRangeY));
    }

    int status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipBitmapGetPixel(new HandleRef(this, nativeImage), x, y, out color);

    if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok)
        throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);

    return Color.FromArgb(color);
}
```

The definition of `SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipBitmapGetPixel` is:

```
[DllImport(ExternDll.Gdiplus, SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)] // 3 = Unicode 
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
internal static extern int GdipBitmapGetPixel(HandleRef bitmap, int x, int y, out int argb);
```

Which we learn from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533971(v=vs.85).aspx) is [`Gdiplus::Bitmap::GetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536297(v=vs.85).aspx). The documentation for that function says:

> ## Remarks
>
> Depending on the format of the bitmap, `Bitmap::GetPixel` might not return the same value as was set by `Bitmap::SetPixel`. For example, if you call `Bitmap::SetPixel` on a Bitmap object whose pixel format is `32bppPARGB`, the pixel's RGB components are premultiplied. A subsequent call to `Bitmap::GetPixel` might return a different value because of rounding. Also, if you call `Bitmap::SetPixel` on a Bitmap object whose color depth is 16 bits per pixel, information could be lost during the conversion from 32 to 16 bits, and a subsequent call to `Bitmap::GetPixel` might return a different value.

Comment: Ok there seems to be no way around this. My picture format is not PARGB but it seems that something similar is going on with PNGs as well.

Comment: @AloisKraus PARGB is just an example.